# Mindstorms EV3 (Micro Python) - Motor.run() not working

Tags: micropython, lego-mindstorms-ev3, pybricks-micropython

I have a Lego Mindstorms EV3 running MicroPython.
When I try to use this code, it does not work:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase, Stop
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import Motor, InfraredSensor
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Direction
from pybricks.tools import wait

# Initialize the EV3 Brick.
ev3 = EV3Brick()

# Initialize Wheels
RightWheel = Motor(Port.B)
LeftWheel = Motor(Port.C)
Robot = DriveBase(LeftWheel, RightWheel, 275.2, 165)
Robot.settings(straight_speed=1000)

# Initialize Motors and Sensors
blade_motor = Motor(Port.D, positive_direction=Direction.CLOCKWISE, gears=None)
infrared_sensor = InfraredSensor(Port.S1)
pressed = infrared_sensor.keypad()

# Play a sound to tell us when we are ready to start moving
ev3.speaker.beep()

LeftWheel.run(1000)
```

If I replace `python LeftWheel.run(1000)` with `python LeftWheel.run_time(1000, 5000)` It works perfectly.

I have no idea why this would happen, I have looked everywhere, and it seems to be just me that is having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program ends, the motors stop.

So if `LeftWheel.run(1000)` is the last thing in your program, nothing appears to happen because the motors stop right away.

It is not recommended to restart `run` over and over in a loop with the same speed as suggested in another answer. This is only useful if you want to change the speed continuously, like when following a line.

Instead, try putting something else after the motor command, like waiting or sounds. Anything that prevents the program from ending right away will do.

```py
LeftWheel.run(1000)
for i in range(10):
    ev3.speaker.beep()
    wait(1000)
```